# Increasing WCF Timeout just increases time it takes for client to acknowledge error

Tags: wcf

We have a wcf service that calls a slow server-side method. This method basically creates a file on the server then returns the path so the client can download that file.

I know the server method completes as the file gets written to the filesystem, the next line of code simply returns the path to this file.

On the client the call obviously gets made but the handler is never invoked, it just sits there until timeout occurs. If I increase the timeout it will just wait longer and just silently fail when the longer timeout incurs. Like I said I can see the remote method is finishing so it isn't actually timing out but somehting is going wrong in the response.

One other possibly relevant point is I have other clients that would be making several different requests to the server during this process but I'm unsure if that is relevant or not.

Server Config:

```
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>     
    <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
     <serviceCredentials>
         <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WebServiceConsumerValidator" />
     </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>  
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>    
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior" name="AlarmNotifierWebService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IAlarmNotifierWebService" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceBinding">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Client config

```
    <bindings>
         <binding name="LiveManagementWebService" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myEndpointBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
  <endpoint address="https://myserver.com/WebServices/ManagementWebService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LiveManagementWebService" contract="IManagementWebService" name="LiveManagementWebService" behaviorConfiguration="myEndpointBehaviour"/>
</client>
```

Note the maxed out values are because this service returns alot of data in some instances.

The calling code:

```
string downloadPath;
using (var managementWebServiceClient = new ManagementWebServiceClient(App.ManagementWebServiceClientName))
{
       managementWebServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
       managementWebServiceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
       managementWebServiceClient.Open();
       // never gets past the following statement:
       downloadPath = managementWebServiceClient.BuildFileAndReturnDownloadUrl("someArg1", "someArg2");        
       managementWebServiceClient.Close();
}

//Fetch the file
var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();                
webClient.DownloadFile(downloadPath , "filename.sdf");
```

The aforementioned other clients call different methods but in the same manner. Any suggestions as to where the problem might be? Happy to provide any further information as required.

Comment: Are you IIS hosted WCF or self? If IIS, have you checked the logs to see which request is causing the issue? Side note: I've been told to avoid `using()` on WCF Proxy Clients.

Comment: What does the WCF trace tell you? You do develop with tracing always turned on, don't you.

Comment: @aliostad, sorry its hanging on the line following the comment, I realise that's not too obvious now, updating.

Comment: @natebros, iis7. Will try without the using and see

Comment: @chris, will check ref the trace situation when I get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

What InstanceContextMode are you using?

If you are implementing the service as a Singleton, then there could be concurrency issues.

Try setting the concurrency to Multiple:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class AlarmNotifierWebService : IAlarmNotifierWebService
{
   // ...
}
```

Another thing to try - what happens if you up the throttling level (the number of allowable concurrent connections)

```
<behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
     <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" /> <!-- The default value is 16 -->
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
     <serviceCredentials>
         <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WebServiceConsumerValidator" />
     </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your info, there is nothing glaringly obvious that could cause the issue.

Your first step must be making sure the client's call is in fact reaching the server. In order to establish that, you have several options:

- Attach your VS (running under Administrator) to w3wp.exe on the server and debug the server side
- Use Fiddler to see if there are any packets going to the server and what is the response
- User Sysinternal's TcpView to see the ports opening and being closed on the client. You could spot firewall issues here as well.

After you have established this fact, update your question accordingly and I will update my answer based on your findings.

Comment: WCF tracing, which should be enabled on both client and service side during development, is a much more focussed tool for establishing exactly what is going on in the WCF infrastructure.